# Express middleware function invocation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, web-development-server

I was watching a tutorial on Express framework and the instructor have used the following code in handling a request.
**The route goes like this:**

```
router.route('/').post(authController.restrictTo('admin', 'lead-guide'));
```

**The handler of the request goes like this:**

```
exports.restrictTo = (...roles) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    /* Some logic related to roles */
    next();
  };
};
```

My question is when the client sends a request to the above specified route then the corresponding handler (restrictTo) is called - This is done by Express. 
But the handler `restrictTo` returns another function (middleware) that takes `req, res, next` as arguments. So that means Express calls the restrictTo first and then waits for it to return another function and call this newly returned function once again with req, res, next parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

In express, middlewares are functions with three arguments `req, res, next`. In a middleware, you only have access to the request, response, and the next function. In your example, he uses a spread operator to add arguments for the middleware function. When he returns the middleware function, it is now basically

```
(req, res, next) => {
    const role = roles[0]; // ACCESS TO ROLES
    /* Some logic related to roles */
    next();
};
```

So to answer your question, it's not exactly waiting but basically **Yes.**

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, but you are close.
The `restrictTo` function is invoked as soon as your application is run.
When `restrictTo` is invoked, it returns a `middleware` function.
Each `middleware` function is then invoked in the order that they are applied.

So for example:

```
const router = express.Router

// No middleware applied yet so any request to this route will go straight to handler i.e.res.json()
router.get('/unrestricted', (req, res, next) => res.json({}));

router.use(authController.restrictTo('admin', 'lead-guide'));

// Any request to this endpoint will pass through the middleware 
// returned by the authController.restrictTo function
router.get('/restricted', (req, res, next) => res.json({}));

// Any request to this route will pass through the restrictTo middleware 
// and another middleware function that will do a console.log 
router.get('/restricted/other', (req, res, next) => {
        console.log('another middleware function');
        next(); 
    }, (req, res, next) => res.json({});
```

**Note:** it is really important that any middleware function should call the `next` function to allow the next function in the chain (be that the handler i.e. the function that will ultimately send the response, or another middleware function etc) to be called.

Comment: I have added a console.log('Before return') before the return in restrictTo and I could as soon as the application is up 'Before return' is printed in the console. - This means that Express tries to execute all the functions that are defined once the server starts. Am 
 I correct and why this is happening prior to any requests made?

Comment: Because you are invoking the function. The creation of your server and routes are all a series of functions which are called when the application starts. A part of this is the application of the middleware functions. The restrictTo function is not middleware. It is a function that when it is called (on application start up) returns a middleware function. That returned middleware function will be called on all routes that the middleware function has been applied to. This is why you see the log on start up.